Firebase Remote Config gradual feature rollout across multiple devices/platforms
We are looking to use Firebase Remote Config for A/B Testing and Gradual feature rollout and we are struggling to setup a proper percentage rollout condition that is also considering users across multiple platforms and devices.
For instance we want to start targeting 10% of our user-base where a user would be identified
across all their apps (iOS, Android and Web).
At the moment I am unable to find such option in Firebase Remote Config condition. I believe this is a pretty common usecase for feature rollouts as I don't want same user to have feature enabled on their iOS app but disabled on Web or the other way around. By same user I mean same authenticated user.
Can you advise if such usecase would be possible with Firebase Remote config?
Firebase doesn't seem to support such usecase, one other option we explored is to actually implement buckets on our codebase and send them to Firebase analytics and then use conditions based on the buckets numbers.
